# Items with android:layout_alignTop still have offset

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `ImageView` and a `TextView` in `RelativeLayout` and I set `layout_alignTop` attribute, but when the view is displayed the items are not horizontally aligned.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_imageView"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/default_img"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@null"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_pro_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A123456"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/iv_imageView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/iv_imageView"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:background="@drawable/back_line"/>
....
</RelativeLayout>
```

I use Dump View UI tool find the offset data. There will be 1px or 2px offset.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: try to set top padding of textview to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_imageView"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:src="@drawable/marker"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@null"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_pro_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A123456"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_imageView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/iv_imageView"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            />

.....
        </RelativeLayout>
```